# How to shrink the widget with make used space of this widget same as interface used?

Tags: flutter

I want to fix the size of the structure of the widget.
When the screen width is smaller than this widget, just shrink this widget.

For this example code, the left text should be inside the red box when the blue container is smaller. The `Transform.scale` widget just shrinks the `child` widget but still uses the same space. I want to shrink the widget and use smaller spaces as you can see.
How to fix that?
Any way can do this without an error?

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  double scale = 1.0;

  Widget targetWidgetBuilder({required bool isStaticTextSize}) => Row(
        children: [
          Transform.scale(
            scale: scale,
            child: Container(
              width: isStaticTextSize ? 100 / scale : 100,
              height: isStaticTextSize ? 100 / scale : 100,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: const Text('A'),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 50),
          Text(scale == 1
              ? 'It should be next to the red box.'
              : 'it should be inside the red box'),
        ],
      );

  late final switchButtonWidget = TextButton(
    onPressed: () => setState(() => scale = scale == 1 ? 0.5 : 1.0),
    child: const Text('switch scale'),
  );
  final screenWidget = Container(
    width: 150, //screen width
    height: 150, //screen width
    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            switchButtonWidget,
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            const Text(
                'You can see this blue container has a smaller size but it still has the same space.'),
            Stack(
              children: [
                screenWidget,
                targetWidgetBuilder(isStaticTextSize: false),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Before click:

[image]

After click:

[image]

This issue makes an error(`A RenderFlex overflowed`).
My widget width is 1000. When the screen width is not the same as this widget, I will shrink it to make it the same but when the screen width is < 1000 although this widget was shrunk, the widget still uses width = 1000. This made all buttons(overflowed) can't press.

Comment: while you are using `const` I am not able to see any usecase for the scale

Comment: I had edited my code example.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve scaling by following code.

```
const scale = 1.0         
return  Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: 100 * scale,
            height: 100 * scale,
            child: Center(
              child: Transform.scale(
                scale: scale,
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  size: 100,
                ),
              ),
            ));
```

Here container used for visualisation only.You can replaced it with SizedBox.

Comment: That isn't what I want. Assume the container width is the screen width, it shouldn't change.

Comment: You can remove width and height from the container. After removing it only icon will scale.

Comment: I think, my post explanation was not good enough but I edited my code example/description. You can see this.